# Handling Loading Images From URL

Tags: android, image, drawable

I have this code that pulls an image from an url and displays it within the app.

```
    Drawable drawableTest = LoadImageFromWeb("http://www.someimageurl");
    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawableTest);

private Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url){
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
    }
 }
```

The method works and the image is pulled into the app without a problem.  What I'd like to do is two things...

1)  Move the process to a background thread.

2)  Display a "loading" drawable (located in drawable folder) while the image is being downloaded and then switch to image when done.  If there's a problem I'd like to load a "unable to load image" drawable (also located in drawable folder).

Can someone help modify the method above so that it will run in the background and display the appropriate images upon loading and if there's a problem?

Thanks!  You guys rock btw.

Shannon

Comment: Exact catch is here: http://goo.gl/nZivF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run the task in another thread. That way, it won't block UI. Roughly, it should be something like this:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

     ProgressDialog pd;

     protected Drawable doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Getting image", true, false);
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url[0]).getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                return d;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
                return null;
            }
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
         /* Image loaded...*/
         pd.dismiss();
         imgView.setImageDrawable(result);

     }
}

MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute("http://www.someimageurl");
```

You can change the `ProgressDialog` with whatever you like...

Comment: This looks awesome and what I'm looking to get working.  I know you said roughly so I suspect it's not complete.  I tried to implement, but getting various errors.. Screenshots Error 1) http://screencast.com/t/bqowMMfTu0WG, Error 2) http://screencast.com/t/NAEFwjNe4qa Error 3) http://screencast.com/t/3AujxtIY Error 4) http://screencast.com/t/98hg9qJbRqS  Any ideas?  Thanks again LAS_VEGAS!  Appreciate the help.

Comment: To fix #2 you need to replace "this" with your "context"

Comment: To fix #3 & 4 you need to put the code `MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute("http://www.someimageurl");` inside a method!

Comment: LOL... Yeah I just figured that out too!  my bad.

Comment: Also change `new URL(url)` with `new URL(url[0])`, I had a mistake there.

Comment: I disabled the diag for now.  I'll fix that after I get it up and working.  The only error I'm getting now is the new URL(url).  It says that I need to change it to a String, but it's already a screen because when I choose "Change to String" it shows it already done.  Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/wbGgHvkY  Any ideas?

Comment: Got it!  Just noticed your correction.  :-)   You're awesome!

Comment: One more question... After I run the task.execute, How do I assign the returned drawable (return d) to the imgView.setImageDrawable(drawableTest) above?

Comment: There was a mistake in `onPostExecute`, I edited it, check it. You need to access `imgView` there in some way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code...

```
         Drawable d;
    LoadImageFromWebThread loadImageFromWebThread=new                                     LoadImageFromWebThread(url);
    loadImageFromWebThread.start();
    imgView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.downloaded);


   class LoadImageFromWebThread extends Thread
   {
       String url; 
       public LoadImageFromWebThread(String url)
       {
           this.url=url;
       }
       @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                 d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
               handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc="+e);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
    }

   }

   final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if(msg.what==0)
            {
                imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
            }
            else
            {
                //Error in downloading image
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I come late into this discussion, but I would like to share the best way I found to load images asynchronously from a given url. 
I am using an android Library called [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/).
To easily load an image using Android query, do the following:

```
    // Init Android Query
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    //fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
    aq.id(R.id.image1).image(url);
```

Hope this will help somebody :)